# XML Import INSPIRE GIS Data

Tags: r, xml, gis

I have a very specific data import problem and I am fairly new to XML data sets, so my problems are probably due to my lack of understanding.
I would like to read in the German track network from Deutsche Bahn, which is published publically here: http://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset/data-streckennetz (link is in Germany unfortunately)

This would be the direct link: http://download-data.deutschebahn.com/static/datasets/streckennetz/INSPIRE_0618.zip

There is also a link to a 200 page document about the INSPIRE data set, but it does not really help me understand parsing the XML document.
https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/documents/Data_Specifications/INSPIRE_DataSpecification_TN_v3.0.pdf

I downloaded the file to my WD and tried to read it using the XML package

```
require(XML)
data <- xmlParse(file.path(Folder,data.file.import), useInternalNodes = FALSE)
root<-xmlRoot(data)
root_child<-xmlChildren(root)
First_child<-root_child[[1]]
xmlName(First_child)
xmlSize(First_child)
xmlAttrs(First_child)
```

Looking at first childe shows the borders of the network I guess

```
<wfs:boundedBy>
< gml:Envelope srsName="urn gc:def:crs:EPSG::4258" srsDimension="2">
< gml:lowerCorner>47.397789564359 6.021325139431</gml:lowerCorner>
< gml:upperCorner>54.907638367755 15.031955280103</gml:upperCorner>
< /gml:Envelope>
< /wfs:boundedBy>
```

The other children do not help me much. The second is a list of names and the third a complex list.

```
Second_child<-root_child[[2]]
Second_child<-root_child[[3]]
```

Can anybody help me somehow or point to a link where I could learn how to parse this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a GML file and so it can be read by the OGR drivers embedded into the `rgdal` and `sf` packages. Hence:

```
> sf::st_layers("./DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml")
Driver: GML 
Available layers:
               layer_name geometry_type features fields
1                 Network            NA        1     12
2     ConditionOfFacility            NA     7072     15
3              MarkerPost         Point    34325     11
4    TrafficFlowDirection            NA     7072     15
5        VerticalPosition            NA     1313     15
[etc]
```

The spatial data in there (ie the layers with a non-NA geometry type) can be read with `sf::st_read`:

```
> nodes = sf::st_read("./DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml","RailwayNode")
Reading layer `RailwayNode' from data source `/home/rowlings/Downloads/SO/train/DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml' using driver `GML'
Simple feature collection with 21457 features and 20 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 6.021325 ymin: 47.39779 xmax: 15.03196 ymax: 54.90462
epsg (SRID):    4258
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
> plot(nodes$geom)
>
```

which produces a set of points that I can see outline Germany quite nicely.

The non-spatial data can also be read with `st_read` and returns a data frame when possible:

```
> ds = sf::st_read("./DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml","DesignSpeed")
Reading layer `DesignSpeed' from data source `/home/rowlings/Downloads/SO/train/DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml' using driver `GML'
Warning message:
no simple feature geometries present: returning a data.frame or tbl_df 
>
```

I guess this is the speed limits for various sections of rail - you'll have to lookup the metadata to see how the IDs match up between tables like this and geographic data:

```
> head(ds)
       gml_id                    identifier applicableDirection fromPosition
1 Spd-2046676 urn:x-dbnetze:oid:Spd-2046676                <NA>            0
2 Spd-2046677 urn:x-dbnetze:oid:Spd-2046677                <NA>            0
3 Spd-2046678 urn:x-dbnetze:oid:Spd-2046678                <NA>            0
4 Spd-2046679 urn:x-dbnetze:oid:Spd-2046679                <NA>            0
5 Spd-2046680 urn:x-dbnetze:oid:Spd-2046680                <NA>            0
6 Spd-2046681 urn:x-dbnetze:oid:Spd-2046681                <NA>            0
[etc etc etc etc]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. For the future, how  could I have found out that i needed to use the `sf` package? One minor question, I assume you did not mean to write `ds = nodes = sf.read(...)` in the second last code chunk? I have to explore the data now and how i merge the sets to draw a map of the tracks for instance collored to indicate the max speed :) Is this a usual Thing that a lot of the fields are almost entirely filled by `NA`

Comment: Given that its GIS data you could have searched for "R and GIS", that might have got you to the "R Spatial Task View" which details classes for spatial data. Have now edited `ds = nodes = ...` which works excepts it overwrite `nodes`...

Comment: Thanks. I will eventually come back with more questions :)

Comment: Hi, I have encoutered an error using the solution for `assign("RailwayLinkSequence",st_read(file.path(Folder, data.file.import),"RailwayLinkSequence"))` could you help me with that? I can read all other layers.

Comment: If you are having a problem with something then best to open a new question with full details and example code rather than trying to squash it into a comment. Tag it [r] and I'll see it.

Comment: Ok, I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53869307/xml-import-inspire-gis-data-layer