# XML Import INSPIRE GIS Data Layer

Tags: r, xml, gis, r-sf

I have a very specific data import problem and I am fairly new to XML data sets, so my problems are probably due to my lack of understanding. I would like to read in the German track network from Deutsche Bahn, which is published publically here: http://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset/data-streckennetz (link is in Germany unfortunately)

This would be the direct link: http://download-data.deutschebahn.com/static/datasets/streckennetz/INSPIRE_0618.zip

There is also a link to a 200 page document about the INSPIRE data set, but it does not really help me understand parsing the XML document. https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/documents/Data_Specifications/INSPIRE_DataSpecification_TN_v3.0.pdf

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701824/xml-import-inspire-gis-data), I got an answer how to read in the layers using the package `sf`

```
sf::st_layers("./DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml")
nodes <- sf::st_read("./DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml","RailwayNode")
```

which worked for all layers but one "RailwayLinkSequence"

```
Link_Sequence<- sf::st_read("./DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml","RailwayLinkSequence")
```

which returns

```
Reading layer `RailwayLinkSequence' from data source `J:\Auswertungen Daten\R Beispiele\GIS\10 Data\DB_Inspire_XML_2015\DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml' using driver `GML'
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 6, 5, 28, 99, 2, 19, 41, 11, 3, 65, 7, 4, 22, 20, 17, 38, 9, 15, 8, 13, 24, 49, 14, 42, 36, 51, 31, 12, 25, 60, 10, 18, 48, 104, 53, 23, 16, 26, 32, 119, 40, 47, 37, 21, 44, 39, 43, 52, 46, 27, 30, 63, 81, 54, 61, 59, 34, 35, 45, 56, 108, 64, 62, 68, 67, 57, 80, 55, 29, 123, 88, 85, 33, 50, 96, 66, 79, 115
In addition: Warning message:
no simple feature geometries present: returning a data.frame or tbl_df
```

Does anybody have a hint why this layer cannot be read in with `st_read`?

Comment: Please post an example of XML in body of question (not as a screenshot or links), with focus on issue node. If too large, abbreviate but include the root and enough to understand the repeating pattern.

Comment: Gladly, but I do not really know what you would like to see and how I should get the example of the XML file?

Comment: You can't post a snippet of `DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml` used in code?

Comment: `st_read` is intended to get spatial information out of spatial files, and GML is a rich file format that can include non-spatial data. A `RailwayLinkSequence` is a non-spatial data, and includes variable numbers of `DirectedLink` elements. To read this in, you probably want to look at R's XML pacakges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xml2` package:

```
> library(xml2)
```

Read the file:

```
> x=  read_xml("./DB-Netz_INSPIRE_20171116.xml")
```

Find all the RLSs in the default (`d1`) namespace:

```
> f = xml_find_all(x, ".//d1:RailwayLinkSequence")
```

Look at one of them:

```
> f[123]
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <RailwayLinkSequence gml:id="LSeq-1829209">\n  <gml:identifier codeSpace= ...
```

How many are there?

```
> length(f)
[1] 7072
```

What's the `localId` value for the 123rd RLS?

```
> xml_find_all(f[123], ".//base:localId")
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <base:localId>LSeq-1829209</base:localId>
```

What are the DirectedLink objects contained in this RLS:

```
> xml_find_all(f[123], ".//net:DirectedLink")
{xml_nodeset (36)}
 [1] <net:DirectedLink>\n  <net:direction>+</net:direction>\n  <net:link xlin ...
 [2] <net:DirectedLink>\n  <net:direction>+</net:direction>\n  <net:link xlin ...
 [3] <net:DirectedLink>\n  <net:direction>+</net:direction>\n  <net:link xlin ...
 [4] <net:DirectedLink>\n  <net:direction>+</net:direction>\n  <net:link xlin ...
 [5] <net:DirectedLink>\n  <net:direction>+</net:direction>\n  <net:link xlin ...
 [...]
```

Learn some more about XML parsing using `xml2` and you'll have to work out how to extract the parts you need for your own purposes. But I hope this helps.